# Why are decoupling capacitors on the VIN of a chip when electrons are flowing from - to + in a DC circut?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

I generally understand what a decoupling capacitor is for and where to put it. Separately, I also understand that electrons flow from - to + in a DC circuit and we just think of current as flowing from + to - for historical reasons. What I don't understand is how these work together. This is one of those topics that's a bit hard to search for.

**Update**

For clarity, here is a great video explaing the physics of a capacitor in terms of electron flow and forces. This is the physcis framework for this question.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_MZNsEqyQw

After thinking about this and the answer below reminding me that decoupling capacitor is also connected to GND near the IC, I think this makes more sense. Im guessing that if the capacitor was connected to GND far from the IC it wouldnt have the same effect.

[image: diagram of flow]

Comment: For the purposes of designing and understanding electronics, the direction of electron flux has almost no bearing and as a fact can be safely deleted from your brain. In other words there is nothing to reconcile between how decoupling capacitors work and the direction of charge carrier flow.

Comment: 1) When talking about circuits, just forget about electrons. Just remember that current flows from + to - through a circuit using power (in a battery, the current does flow from - to +). 2) Currents flow in **loops**. 3) Decoupling capacitors are like "voltage resevoirs" that can absorb a quickly changing current (when something switches on/off in an IC) so the current change goes through the decoupling capacitor and not through the battery that could be "far away". 4) As a beginner, don't worry too much about decoupling caps, just know they are needed. How they work will become clear later.

Comment: This is a great example of how caring about electron flow vs conventional current flow screws people up coming into EE.

Comment: Nothing is screwing me up; Im trying to understand.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what, exactly, you are failing to understand?  It is hard to determine from your question and comments here.  Lots of people here are great at explaining these things, we just need to know more about what part is holding you up.

Comment: Maybe "screws up" is a little extreme, but certainly "adds unnecessary confusion."

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to bring electrons into this, or which way they flow.

The decoupling capacitor has to go across the power supply terminals of the IC, to locally source surges of current drawn by the IC. The two supply terminals of a 'single supply' IC are VCC and GND. The capacitor is therefore placed between VCC and GND.

Often in schematics, many devices have a GND terminal, and they all connect to the same GND node, usually a plane. To avoid cluttering the schematic with excess wires, these connections are usually shown in abbreviated form, and as such, can often get overlooked.

Answer (score 3):

Electrons (or better yet, a current which is mathematically more convenient to work with than individual electrons), does flow from source through load back to the source in the DC case. I'm going to talk about current and not electron flow throughout this post. (The fact that electrons flow from - to + is a historical artifact and irrelevant)

In the case of a pure DC current, the decoupling capacitors don't do much. The current flows from source through load back to source in a loop.

However, chips aren't *quite* DC devices - they expect an unchanging DC *voltage* but draw a changing current which is DC with some AC superimposed.  In one picosecond, a chip might draw 1 mA. Then the clock edge happens and it draws 1.5 mA for a few picoseconds, then 0.9 mA, and back to 1 mA.

These sudden changes in current are fulfilled from the nearby capacitors, which have much less *inductance* and *impedance* than the power supply lines. The inductance and impedance of the supply lines causes the voltage seen by the chip to fluctuate as its current draw fluctuates (this follows from V = IR for the series resistance of the supply, and V = L dI/dt for series inductance). This might cause unreliable operation or even total malfunction. The issue is even worse with increasing frequency - an inductance of mere nanohenries can contribute double-digit impedance at 2.4 GHz (for example).

On the other hand, the capacitors are mounted close to the chip, with small loop area. This reduces the impedance and inductance that AC currents must encounter, and hence keeps the supply voltage stable at the supply pins.

Comment: Thats a great explanation for what a decoupling capacitor is, but I already knew that and thats not my question. Im looking to understand the physics of this.

Comment: @craig.tadlock your post did not make that clear. The physics is exactly the physics behind ohmic impedance and the inductance in a loop -- Wikipedia or Halliday/Resnick/Walker are both great references here as a starting point to knowing what exactly you want clarified.

Answer (score 0):

They don't work together, they are two completely different concepts.

Bypass caps are needed close to the positive and negative terminals of any chip, regardless of which way electrons or current flows.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a common convention.  There is no difference if the cap is placed close to the Vcc pin or closer to the Gnd pin (assuming there is only one of each).
It's a closed loop, so as the cap moves from being close to the Vcc pin, to mid-way, to close to the Gnd pin, the trace inductance moves and splits, but it's generally the same amount.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGLlgY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>